# Where is Visual Studio Build Action stored?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm writing a parser to pull data from various programs.
Some of the programs have "Build Action" set to "None" and I want to skip them.
I was guessing that this property would be in the .csproj, .btproj file, but I don't see it there.  So my question is where is it stored?

I'm specifically dealing with BizTalk orchestrations, but I think the same concept would apply to C# and C# project files as well.  I'm using Visual Studio 2015 to be compatible with BizTalk 2016.

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for Solution->Context Menu->Configuration Manager?

Comment: @PMF No, I don't think so.  I presume it that "Build Action" has to be stored in some file that I can read with my parser program.

Comment: Ah, got it. Show your project file, please.

Comment: I found it and posted answer.  When I looked at the file again now, it became more obvious.   Before, I was looking for "build" "build action" or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to create a "None" XML element in the .btproj file as shown below.
I was expecting to be an attribute or element value, not an xml element itself.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Orchestrations\PublishPIHistoricalData_v2.odx">
      <SubType>Task</SubType>
      <TypeName>PublishPIHistoricalData_v2</TypeName>
      <Namespace>ABC.Integration.BizTalk.ProcessDataHistorian.Orchestrations</Namespace>
    </None>
```

whereas a compiled orchestration will look like this:

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <XLang Include="Orchestrations\PublishPIDataODS.odx">
      <SubType>Task</SubType>
      <TypeName>PublishPIData_ODS</TypeName>
      <Namespace>ABC.Integration.BizTalk.ProcessDataHistorian.Orchestrations</Namespace>
    </XLang>
```

Comment: Yea, that's it. Explicitly specifying a `None` operation includes a file with no operation. You might even see entries like `<Compile remove...` to remove something that is included by default (such as a cs file that's explicitly excluded)